# Controller Instance created and destroyed for each request in MVC - WebAPI - What dependency scope to inject?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection, castle-windsor

I am developing a `WebAPI` application.

And as I understand `WebAPI` and `MVC`, `every time a request comes, a new instance of the API-Controller is created and it is disposed after the request is served`.

Also, to inject dependency I use `castle-windsor`.

```
     aContainer.Register(Component
        .For<IDataProvider>()
        .ImplementedBy<DataProvider>()
        .LifestyleScoped());

    aContainer.Register(Component
        .For<IDataProvider>()
        .ImplementedBy<DataProvider>()
        .LifestylePerWebRequest());
```

The question here is I am very confused with using `LifeStyleScoped` and `LifeStylePerRequest`. The documentation is pretty vast and I am lost.

Can anyone tell me whats the impact of using each of them in a `WebAPI` context ?

Comment: Mark Seeman has a nice explanation on how to use Castle Windsor for WebAPI projects: http://blog.ploeh.dk/2012/10/03/DependencyInjectioninASP.NETWebAPIwithCastleWindsor/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you try to think outside of the Web stack you will see that LifeStyleScoped is not confusing at all. It just marks the begin and the end of an object`s lifecycle. I have seen implementation of UnitOfWork pattern with scoped lifetime which provides a capability like nested transactions with roll back - nested units of work - or multiple during the same request/action.

LifestylePerWebRequest is the default lifestyle of Controllers - you do not want your Controllers to live more then the request, because they are there just to serve your request and nothing more.

You can inject whatever you want into a Controller. Of course you must take care to release your components. For example - You make singleton lifestyle implementation of IMyService and inject it into the Controller (If you make the injected services as private members then they will be thread safe too because their method stack frame is different for every method call). This way you will have the same instance of IMyService for every request. At the end of the app lifecycle or other 'application end' event you must release everything. Especially SQL connections.

If you take this further down the object resolution graph it may turn out that you have IUnitOfWork which has scoped lifetime and you make and dispose several of them during IMyService.DoTheJob();

As a conclusion - you may inject whatever you want into your controller but remember to release some of the objects that have "greater lifetime scope" then PerWebRequest and are not needed after the particular request.